# Sqlite JDBC driver not supporting RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I am using Xerial latest jdbc driver for sqlite (version 3.7.2) It does not seem to have support for Statement RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS. I keep getting "not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver" in the SQLException.

I really do not want to make another select call (e.g select id from tasks order by 1 desc limit 1 ) in order to get the latest Id created by an auto-increment field. I need to use that id to populate a field in another table.

Are there any better ways of achieving this using sqlite-jdbc driver ?

Comment: If the driver won't support it, you either need a new driver, another database, or writing the SELECT yourself.  There's no guarantee that the example query you gave will work for multiple simultaneous users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If upgrading/replacing the JDBC driver is not an option (the [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) seem to support it), then you really need to fire a `SELECT last_insert_rowid()` query to obtain the generated key. To avoid race conditions with concurrent inserts, fire it in a transaction.

```
connection = database.getConnection();
connection.setAutoCommit(false); // Starts transaction.
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);
preparedStatement.setSomething(something);
// ...
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
statement = connection.createStatement();
generatedKeys = statement.executeQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid()");
if (generatedKeys.next()) {
    generatedKey = generatedKeys.getLong(1);
}
connection.commit(); // Commits transaction.
```

Comment: SQLiteJDBC driver that you mentioned was the first one I tried. Someone suggested to use Xerial instead. In either case, I got "not supported". I am running JDBC on MAC

Comment: The JDBC driver you mentioned does not implement the necessary JDBC methods for getting the generated keys...

Answer (score 6):

I'm also using sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar and found that using `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` does fail, however merely doing a `statement.execute(sql)` followed by `resultset = statement.getGeneratedKeys()` and `meta = resultset.getMetaData()` shows that a column name `last_insert_rowid()` is available in the resultset. So `resultset.getInt("last_insert_rowid()")` does indeed return the newly inserted rowid without an additional select.